# Is there any person who experienced the subtle body temporarily leaving body due to vichara?

Tags: mantras, yoga, body, jnana

There are several stories in which I heard people experiencing their subtle body leaving their physical body for some time and coming back into it.

One of them is  [HH Sri Siddheswarananda Bharati](https://www.siddheswaripeetham.org/present-swamiji/). He experienced his jiva leaving his body temporarily while chanting the Hanuman mantra with devotion for a long time.

I heard this phenomenon in Yogis also.

But I never heard about such a phenomenon in the persons who opted for vichara/jnana marga.

Is there any person either in scriptures or contemporary days who experienced the phenomenon by mere and intense vichara?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I mean sushma sareera

Comment: You mean Sookshma or Sukshma. It's not Sushma.

Comment: @MrGreenGold Thanks. Its Sukshma yeah..

Comment: Jnana yoga normally results in realisation and rarely gives yogic powers like out of body travel. Jnana yoga just gives realisation it may or may not give yogic powers

Comment: So there was one video of Sadhguru. According to him, there was a person who used to live near Chamunda Hill who had knowledge. He wanted to quit his body but didn’t know how to. Sadhguru taught him the necessary yogic sadhana to do that and person left his body. Conclusion: gyaan without sadhana may not be giving siddhis

Comment: @Archit Sorry, I cannot consider him as an authentic personality... At least for now... Maybe I can consider it later...